# Does the Lightning Network support Bitcoin scripts, and what do the identifiers of Lightning wallets look like?

Tags: lightning-network, script

I'm currently exploring the deployment of Bitcoin scripts within the Lightning Network. Specifically, I'm interested in understanding the compatibility and functionality of Bitcoin scripts within the Lightning Network protocol.

Firstly, I'd like to know if the Lightning Network supports Bitcoin scripts. Are Lightning Network transactions able to utilize Bitcoin scripts for custom smart contract functionality, similar to on-chain Bitcoin transactions?

Secondly, I'm curious about the identifiers of Lightning wallets. When interacting with the Lightning Network, do Lightning wallet identifiers resemble traditional Bitcoin addresses? Or are there distinct formats or structures used for Lightning wallet identifiers, considering the off-chain nature of Lightning transactions?

I appreciate any insights or resources that can shed light on these questions.